# How do I duplicate an audio CD on Lion without importing tracks into iTunes?

Tags: applications, audio, cd-burning

I want to create an exact duplicate of an audio CD on my Mac (Lion). Is there a way that does not involve to import the CD into iTunes? I just don't want to remember that I have to delete the tracks after copying. And I'm not sure if importing and burning again really creates an exact copy. (Track gaps preserved, and so on)

I tried using Finder, Crtl-click the CD, select duplicate. Ctrl-click the resulting Folder and select burn to CD, but that left my with a data CD containing AIFF-Files.

Any ideas, or AppStore suggestions?

Comment: Do you own the copyright?

Comment: Does that make a difference to the answer, or are you just trying to remind me, that I should not steal other peoples intellectual property?

Comment: it does make a difference, if you do not then this promotes illegal activity and is unwelcome on the site, just a disclaimer, see below for software recommendations

Comment: Oh, yes you are right, I didn't think about that. I just checked and indeed have the right to create a copy in my home country.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Toast](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/) ($99)

Lets you capture, copy, convert, share and burn discs

or

### [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html) (open source)

again does the same but a more basic version which is free.

Comment: I know about Toast, it's a great software, but a little overkill for this. So I'll try Burn first.

Comment: Burn is good considering it's a free piece of software.

Comment: +1 for Toast. I love it! Even if it does cost something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Disk Utility (included in OS X, `Applications -> Utilities -> Disk Utility`) to create an image of a music CD. You can then eject the source disk and with the same Disk Utility you can burn the disk image to a blank CD-R.

Comment: You can't do this with Disk Utility. It's greyed out for Audio CDs.

Comment: I tried creating an image of the CD using Disk Utility to copy to a blank disk. The problem I encountered was that the disk image created by Disk Utility was larger than the free space available on a standard CD so it didn't allow me to copy the disk image on the CD.